# Deploying web app to on-prem server using Azure Pipelines

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using Azure DevOps pipelines to build and deploy web application to on-prem servers.

[image]

The deployment is working but the release seems to be creating an offline website which is a non functional website under IIS.  The deployment tasks do deploy the correct artifacts into the actual website folder, but the odd offline WebSite that it creates is not a functional website:  I'm attaching a snapshot of what we see in IIS.

[image]

Am I using the wrong configuration type?  I've tried the other options but get errors with the configurations.

I was expecting the website would be updated but not that the release task would create a new WebSite.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your “testblaz” directory and make sure the “web config” file exist. If not ,your  “testblaz”  couldn’t be a functional website. You maybe miss some important tasks in creating pipeline.

Please follow below steps to deploy web app to on-prem server using azure pipelines:

1 create a pipeline that includes 3 tasks: build project and publish project and publish artifacts.

a YAML pipeline example:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:  
buildConfiguration: 'Release' 

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
displayName: 'dotnet build'  
inputs:
 command: 'build'
 projects: '*/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2  
displayName: 'dotnet publish'  
inputs:  
 command: 'publish'  
 publishWebProjects: true  
 arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'  
   
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1  
displayName: 'Publish artifacts'  
inputs:  
 targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'  
 publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

2 After the pipeline running successfully, it would publish an artifact automatically that will be used in IIS Deploy Website.
[image: pipeline]

3 create a release pipeline and config the “Package or Folder” generated by step 2. (File path to the package or a folder generated by MSBuild or a compressed archive file)
[image: release]
The Package look likes below:
[image: package or folder]
4 You will see a functional website in IIS after deploying the release successfully.
[image: website in IIS]

5 browse the demo website.
[image: browse website]

**update**

1 The other WebSite `testblaz` with black spot seems like that it has been stopped. Please `start` the website and see if it works.

2 deploy `testblaz` in your local with Visual studio or add website manually in IIS then see if it creates the other stopped website. If it creates other website, please check your web project directory and code. If not, please follow my YANL example pipeline to deploy the website app. And see if it works.

Comment: If it helps, just a remind of accept an answer. If not, i‘ll stay focused on your new issue.

Comment: The odd behavior is that the pipeline actually updates the web app folder that is indicated in the release configuration.  But it also creates the other WebSite which is not connected to anything (the non working website shown in the original post).  The TestBlaz Website with the WebSite symbol (blue earth icon).  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Woofies I've updated my answer. Hope it can help you.